# Denied Boarding

Tags: istanbul, turkish-airlines, panama, dominican-republic, denied-boarding

On the 21st of November I had a connecting flight on Turkish Airlines from Lahore (Pakistan) to Santo Domingo (Dominican Republic) via Istanbul amd Panama City.

In Istanbul, when the Panama City flight was boarding, I was denied boarding. They said that I do not have a Panama transit visa. Such a visa was not required in my case, as I had only a 4 hour stay there and my destination country was the Dominican Republic. Later I was told the reason was "you did not have a valid visa."

I can prove I had a genuine valid business visa and I have been unfairly denied. I want compensation, but the airline says no, and keeps on giving different reasons for my denied boarding. I have consulted my lawyer, who advised me to catch them on social media first, but I am not sure whether it's worth it or not. I want to directly contact higher authorities of Turkish Airlines about my case. I don't think Customer Care is seriously considering my case.

What can I do? And how can I prevent this in future?

Comment: It sounds like you need to consult a lawyer

Comment: I agree with Traveller.

Comment: Were you travelling with checked bags?  Were these checked all the way through to your final destination?  Did you already have a boarding pass for the final flight?  Did you have a return ticket to leave the Dominican Republic at a later date?

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: Even though TK sells tickets LHE-IST-PTY-SDQ, their site displays a weird "Stopovers (No Connecting Flight) for Bogota, Colombia" (!) followed by "Layovers & Connecting Flights for Panama City, Panama". Looking up TK800, it seems it's an Istambul-Bogota-Panama City-Istambul flight, though Colombia also allows TWOV for transit so that shouldn't change things much. Unless they can't transfer luggage to the flight to SDQ (and in that case I would expect them to have a big warning about that), I don't quite see a reason for the denied boarding if it was all booked as a single ticket...

Comment: i have been given 3 boarding passes which were from Lahor to Istanbul and istanbul to Panama and Panama to Santo Domingo. And i had a confirmed return ticket as well. And my luggage was also checked and i have been asked you will collect yourluggage at Santo Domingo. Please advise me what action should i take against the airline to compensate me as they have denied compensating me and accepting their mistake

Comment: Please someone advise me how to claim my damages from Turkish Airlines now as they have denied giving me any conpensation and didn't accept their mistake. They say what ever they have done was according to the rules. I can still guarantee my all documents were genuine...

Comment: Any update on this? Did the airline compensate you? Can someone please move this to the comments section? I am new to stackexchange and dont have enough points to post a comment. Thanks